Simplifying model interface while using diff undo-redo?
Introduction & context
I am working (hobby) on a CAD/CAM (mostly CAM) solution. It is a desktop application in C++, Qt, OpenGL, JavaScript and CMake.

General Undo/Redo strategies
Most desktop application implement some type of Undo-Redo mechanism. All strategies to implement undo/redo relay on a linked-list of states that can be applied in one or the other direction.
Depending on the type of applications, variants of the following 3 strategies are implemented:

Command pattern: each operation has it reverse operation. Good when there is always an obvious reverse operation. This unfortunately become unefective for destructive operations.
Full snapshot: each operation saves a full snapshot of the document. Easy to implement, but not practical when the snapshot takes time to be created or applied.
Deltas of snapshots: each operation saves a shallow (incomplete) snapshot, only with the relevant change.

Considering that CAD/CAM internal model is quite complex (several hundreds of MBytes) to manipulate 3D mesh/BRep, polylines, etc. I applied the third technique. Additionally, the datastructure cannot be easily converted to text, making difficult to apply existing diff tools on a serialized version of the model.
For this technique, I evaluated 2 possible implementations in C++

Using polymorphism: The model is a tree of optional nodes, a delta (shallow) copy have most nodes empty, and only changed nodes are set.
Templates: similar, but using templates

enum class IsDelta
{
    Full,
    Delta
};

template <IsDelta O>
class CamModel<IsDelta>
{
    ... the model here
};

CamModel<Full> currentFullState; // Full copy of the current state
circular_queue<CamModel<Delta>, MAX_HISTORY> history;
size_t current_idx = 0; //0 is the last, 1 the previous....


I am using the templates for the moment.
Datastructures requirements
For the application model (data-structure of the project), I identified 4 types of  composition:

Values without history: values that cannot be undone (e.g. selection)
Simple properties: Unique properties that requires Undo/Redo
List or vectors: Multi-valuated, ordered set of values. We need to apply undo/redo to a subset of values (ids)
Dictionaries: Multi-valuated, unordered set of values. We need to apply undo/redo to a subset of values (keys)

Simple deltas are implemented as follow:
template <typename T>
class DeltaValue
{
public: 
    ... // accessors, constructors, destructors, ...
private:
    std::optional<T> m_before;
    std::optional<T> m_after;
};

// A value is either an object of the given type, or a delta, containing
// optional state before, and optional state after.
template <typename T, IsDelta O>
using SimpleMaybeDelta = std::conditional_t<O==IsDelta::Yes, DeltaValue<T>,  T>;

// Example
template <IsDelta O>
class CamModel<IsDelta>
{
    SimpleMaybeDelta<DocumentMeta,O> m_projectMetadata;
};

With this, the structure of the project is defined once, and we end with two structures:

The full CamModel contains simply the DocumentMeta property called m_projectMetadata
A Delta CamModel contains an object m_projectMetadata.m_after and m_projectMetadata.m_before, each of them optional.

For multi-valued elements, the strategy is the same, but the delta saves the operation type (insert, delete, modify) and the idx / key.
How to edit values
Changes to the model are currently implemented directly as deltas:
CamModel<IsDelta::Delta> delta;
auto meta = model().projectMetadata().convertToDelta();
meta.setProjectName("New Project name");
delta.setProjectMetadata(delta); // set m_after to the new delta value
history.pushChange( delta); // This propagates the change to all the application

This works fine, however, it's very verbous for modifying a single value. And it gets worse the deeper is the delta in the model.
The problem
When the model structure gets deeper, creating each level of deltas to asign a value becomes more and more verbous.
Also, I have added a JavaScript engine to allow working command-line ( and to disconnect more the dependency from the GUI and the model).
I would like the JavaScript wrapper to be simple:
current_document().current_state().project_metadata().set_project_name("New Project name")

This is currently no possible due to the need of creating the delta, and providing the transaction to the history.
Re-implementing fully the history is a possibility.
I am looking for a better architecture for undo/redo, allowing simpler interface to modify values


I would like the JavaScript wrapper to be simple.

Recommend that you version the CAD/CAM project
using off-the-shelf git.
Then any given snapshot can be summarized with a SHA1 hash.
You can choose to optimize specific undo / redo operations for speed,
relying on the git representation as arbiter of what is "correct"
behavior.

the datastructure cannot be easily converted to text [files]

Well, that's not necessarily a deal breaker.
You will certainly want to maintain binary assets
for things like texture bump maps.
Hopefully they are "small" and change seldom.
Git can represent any binary file with just its SHA1 hash.
What's important is that subassemblies appear in different files.
Suppose you have a complex hood ornament.
During an interactive session a designer chooses to attach
it to the hood here, then there, then puts it back here.
The ornament, and its binary file, never changes.
It has a simple relationship to the hood,
with a compact representation well suited for undo / redo.
Finding the "cleavage points" for subassemblies
will be important to the success of your project's refactoring.
And finding ways to support line-oriented text diffs,
while not essential, will always be a nice-to-have.
The great thing about using git is it's battle tested --
you know it works.

Dictionaries: Multi-valued, unordered set of values.

I respectfully disagree about the "unordered" aspect.
Yes, I know the math definition of a mapping.
But for a practical implementation I recommend you
adopt some deterministic serialization, such as

preserve insert() order, as python does, or
lexically order the keys, in the interest of simplicity


This app would benefit from deployment on a file system that offers fast CoW version snapshots, such as ZFS.
A SAN such as NetApp can offer similar functionality.
Then an asynchronous git process can grovel over binary CAD files in the background.
Avoid requesting too frequent FS snapshots by waiting for each git commit to finish.
Thus the undo granularity becomes coarser during periods of rapid interactive updates.
The app can also log hints, a sequence of recently updated filenames, to aid the efficiency of the background task.
An OS “watch” interface, such as kqueue, can accomplish the same thing.
Rely on atomic file renames, so the background task never sees an inconsistent partially written file.

Does not convince me. I think in practice, including Git (or any other SCCS) in such a process becomes impracticle. One would first serialize/snapshot the whole CAD/CAM model into a set of files (several hundred MBs, as the OP wrote), then do some mutation within the model, serialize again and then let the SCCS figure out the changes. Though the SCCS will detect and store only the difference between two revisions (which is surely memory efficient), it will be extremely hard to make this approach work fast enough for several small, little changes to the CAD/CAM model.

... Moreover, a tool like Git seems to be heavily oversized just for storing a list of sequential changes.

@DocBrown, that’s why I emphasized the importance of breaking subassemblies along appropriate cleavage points, and writing app-specific undo / redo routines for “small” changes, while letting git be the backstop that can always handle the general case.

The command pattern with "reverse operations" is IMHO the right approach to start with - and your strategies #2 and #3 (full deltas or partial deltas) should be simply implementation variants for the reverse operations of certain commands.
So you can pick

a simple command implementation for simple-to-revert operations (like changing a single value, or applying an affine transformation to a certain part of the model's geometry)

a more complex implementation based on partial or full snapshots for any complex operation with no easy reversal.

something in-between for specific operations where you can limit the resulting changes to some known area of the model


There should be a layer of commands for mutations to the model, and any mutating operation should be routed through this layer exclusively. That layer should be used from your GUI as well as from your Javascript wrapper, which should solve your Javascript issue.
You already analysed (and generalized) the structure of your model's data, which is a good start. Still I think it is more important that you analyse and categorize the mutating operations your system shall support. Instead of trying to develop a "one-size-fits-all" reversal algorithm, choose an appropriate command implementation for each category of operations. That might help you to solve your issues.
To your example of "editing a value": I guess such an operation has to rely on a generic implementation of setting a value to a property by using something like a node(id), the property's name and the new value (I assume the properties belong to something like a node with a unique ID, where the ID is independent from the location of the node in memory). Then you can easily make a command out of it, with it's obvious reverse operation ("set property in the same node to its old value"), and implement this once. Even if that implementation looks verbose to you, that should not be great deal, since it will only exist in one place of the code base - calling this generic implementation will be as easy as
     EditPropertyCommand editCmd(myNodeId,"myNodeName",myNewValue);
     editCmd.execute();   // will internally push the reverse command to the history


Due to the complexity of most commands (e.g. an extruding operation on a model will generate, remove, and modify vertices, surfaces and edges all in one), I would need to choose an appropriate level of granularity for the commands: either modify very simple elements (as said vertices, surfaces, edges..) in a transaction or implement more complex commands all in one. (Continues)

Considering that delta-snapshots are still required in any case, the key point of this solution seems to be "There should be a layer of commands for mutations of the model, and any motation operation should be routed through this layer exclusively", basically, you are proposing a command wrapper around the partial snapshots ? I will indeed research more this approach.

@AdrianMaire: I am proposing a command layer for all mutations. If you need a partial snapshot for making some of these commands work effectively, then you can call it "a command wrapper around the partial snapshot", if you like. I prefer to call it an implementation detail of the commands, and it is probably not needed for any type of command. Though it may be a matter of perspective: undoing a simple "set property to value" by remembering the old value of that property might be seen as a "partial snapshot", too, but just a very lightweight one.

Thank you for the clarification :-)
